# Linkedin Authentication popup not working ? in Chrome

Tags: linkedin-api

@JustinKominar @justinKominar I
'm still getting this error although my code is exactly like the documentation?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
       api_key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
         authorize: true
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
     </script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

      function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
      }

      function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

     function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address)").result(onSignIn).error(onError);
    }

    function liAuth(){
      IN.User.isAuthorized(function(){
        callback();
      });
    }
    </script>
```

> error in the chrome console dev tools point to
>
> ```
> function liAuth(){
>         IN.User.authorize(function(){
>             callback();
>         });
> ```

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined
    (anonymous function) @ VM9423:15
    (anonymous function) @ framework?v=0.0.1195-RC8.54174-1429&lang=undefined:3632
    liAuth @ VM9423:14
    onclick @ (index):1
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot fo searching online,  it was as simple as going to the Chrome settings and clearing out LinkedIn cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You have called the callback function but didn't defined. Create a callback function.